How do I make the process of switching between mix shader images easier or faster?
I have images that I would like to switch between in animation. They are directional movements of a 2D character and use Mix Shaders to keyframe to another direction. I was wondering if there is a better way to change the images in animation without having to set multiple Mix Shaders to 0 or 1 each time.

For example, I have 8 directions so would there be a way to simply change the direction with a value between 1-8?
Also, within the grouped nodes I have the two images, one being a image sequence that represents the character walking and the other being the characters idle pose for that direction. I have it connected to the input so they can be switched outside the group.


Unrelated, but is there a reason for mixing sgaders instead of images? If the only difference between all the shaders is the one image texture you plug into them, then you could instead mix the textures and plug whatever the result into one shader type node, making the whole material simpler to use and to compute.

You can use a value node with compare nodes to make the factors
You can also use another property of the material, one that you may set with geometry nodes and get with an "Attribute" shader node, and maybe animate. ( How to use output in Group Output geometry node? )

